# The Game of Nim

Tags: python, game

I am currently looking for a language to program a game for my FYP which is to program the game "The game of nim". I am currently looking at pygame for this program, I hope someone can give me suggestions on any other language. I did made a simple python program which use console to show the rock and stuff, but I need to make an UI for it.

```
import random
from tokenize import Name

def main():
    StoneList=[]
    StonePile=random.randint(2,5)
    StoneQuantity=random.randint(1,9)
    Name=input("Enter Your name:")
    print("Hello ",Name,"! Welcome to the Game of Nim")
    player=Name
    Board(StoneList,StonePile,StoneQuantity,player)

def Board(StoneList,StonePile,StoneQuantity,player):
    #Print out the board
    for i in range(0,StonePile):
        StoneQuantity=random.randint(1,8)
        print("Pile {}:---{} Stones on this pile-----{}".format(i+1,StoneQuantity,'O'*StoneQuantity))
        StoneList.append(StoneQuantity)
    print("** 'O' represent stone **")
    
    CalculateNim(StoneList,StonePile,player)


def Get_Input(StoneList,StonePile,player):
    while True:
            stones=input(player+",How many stones you want to remove? ")
            piles=input("Which pile you want to remove from? ")

            if(stones and piles)and(stones.isdigit()) and (piles.isdigit()):
                if(int(stones)>0) and (int(piles)>0) and (int(piles)<=len(StoneList)):
                    if(int(stones)<=StoneList[int(piles)-1]):
                        if(int(stones)!=0) and (int(piles)!=0):
                            break
            
            print("Invalid input, please try again")
    
    StoneList[int(piles)-1]-=int(stones)
    
    proceed(StoneList,StonePile,player)
    CalculateNim(StoneList,StonePile,player)

def proceed(StoneList,StonePile,player):
    print("Current Board:")
    for i in range(0,StonePile):
        print("Pile {}:---{} Stones on this pile-----{}".format(i+1,StoneList[i],"O"*StoneList[i]))
    print("** 'O' represent stone **")
    if(StoneList==[0]*len(StoneList)):
        print("Game Over, Bot Won. Thanks for playing!")
        exit()

def CalculateNim(StoneList,StonePile,player):
    nim=0
    for i in StoneList:
        nim=nim^i
    if(nim==0):
        #If Nim-Sum=0, Player start first
        Get_Input(StoneList,StonePile,player)
    else:
        #If Nim-Sum is not equal to 0, Bot start first
        BotTurn(StoneList,StonePile,player)


def BotTurn(StoneList,StonePile,player):
    print("BOT's TURN")
    nim=0
    for i in StoneList:
        nim=nim^i
    
    counter=0
    for i in StoneList:
        if((nim^i)<i):
            print("Bot take {} stone(s) from Pile {}".format(StoneList[counter]-(nim^i),counter+1))
            StoneList[counter]=(nim^i)

            break
        counter=counter+1  
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    proceed(StoneList,StonePile,player)
    CalculateNim(StoneList,StonePile,player)


        
        
    
main()
```

Comment: If you're looking for a new language to learn, maybe you should write it in [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/)

Answer (score 3):

```
    Name = input(...)
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you use the identifier `name`, downcased.
Similarly for `stone_list`, `stone_pile`, `stone_quantity`,
`def get_list()` and the like.

You are the programmer, you make the rules -- be decisive.
Are we talking about a "name" or a "player" here?
Either identifier would do nicely.
Pick one.

```
    Board(StoneList, StonePile, StoneQuantity, player)

def Board(StoneList, StonePile, StoneQuantity, player):
```

Wow, I did not see that one coming.

Having read the final line of `main`, I believed
we were instantiating a `Board` object and then I
was about to draw a noun / verb distinction, asking
you not to get carried away with lots of actions
within a constructor, preferring e.g. `Board(...).play()`.
But then the next line tells me that, "surprise!",
it's a function instead. Which brings us back to the
topic of choosing appropriate names. Use a capital noun for a Class,
and a lower verb for a function such as this one.
Consider `def display_board()`, for example.

```
    stone_pile = random.randint(2, 5)
```

That is slightly verbose, and we make several such calls.
Prefer `from random import randint` so you can shorten it.
That way the Gentle Reader's train of thought will remain
firmly fixed on the idea you're trying to express, without
being distracted by "Bond, James Bond, Integer Bond"
redundancies.

```
    CalculateNim(...)
```

OIC, this function doesn't do just a
[single](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
thing. We could call it "display and play",
but probably better to make it the caller's
responsibility to invoke `calculate_nim(...)`.

Ok, that's as much as I'm going to read through.

---

This code appears to achieve some of its design goals.
I would not be willing to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks for this codebase in its current form.

You have started your journey and you're
keen to learn, that's good.
I encourage you to read other people's code and
reflect on the choices they made. There are diverse
ways to get the machine to compute the same thing,
but some ways make it easier for others to understand
and maintain working source code.
I encourage you to keep writing code and then
go back to critique your own code.
What did I write yesterday?
Is it clear to me today?
How can I improve it today?
What might I have focused on yesterday
so there's no need for refactoring today?
I wish you luck.

Answer (score 3):

**PEP8 Style ([reference](https://pep8.org))**

- [standardize naming](https://pep8.org/#overriding-principle)

  - lowercase_with_underscores (ex: `CalculateNim` to `calulate_nim`, you seem to use multiple styles, this comment is to pick one and stick with it, the general standard being lowercase_with_underscores)

I would recommend wrapping everything in a class so that:

- you don't have to pass variables around
- integrating with GUI later will be easier

I would rename a few variables to be more descriptive and follow PEP8

The `__init__` will mimic current `Board` method

```
class Nim:

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player
        self.num_piles = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.init_piles()

    def init_piles(self):
        self.stones_list = []
        for _ in range(0, self.num_piles):
            self.stones_list.append(random.randint(1, 8))

Board = Nim(input("Enter Your name: "))
```

Create a utility function to get number input, so that the error message can be custom, and `get_input` can be simplified

- prompt: what prompted to user
- max: max number allowed
- allowed: mainly for piles prompt, list of piles with stones left

```
    ...
    def get_number_input(self, prompt, max, allowed=[]):
        num = ''
        while True:
            num = input(prompt)
            if not num.isdigit():
                print("Not a Number, please try again")
            elif int(num) <= 0 or int(num) > max:
                print("Out of Range, please try again")
            elif len(allowed) > 0 and int(num) not in allowed:
                print("No stones in pile, please try again")
            else:
                break
        return int(num)

    def get_input(self):
        pile_pick = self.get_number_input(
          "Which pile you want to remove from? ", len(self.stones_list),
          [i + 1 for i, s in enumerate(self.stones_list) if s > 0])
        num_stones = self.get_number_input(
          "{}, How many stones you want to remove from pile {}? ".format(
            self.player, pile_pick), self.stones_list[pile_pick - 1])
    
        self.stones_list[pile_pick - 1] -= num_stones
```

To run the game use something like:

```
class Board:
    ...
    def start(self):
        print("Hello {}! Welcome to the Game of Nim".format(self.player))
        while self.proceed():
            self.calculate_nim()
    def proceed(self):
        self.print()
        if (self.stones_list == [0] * len(self.stones_list)):
            print("Game Over, Bot Won. Thanks for playing!")
            return False
        return True
...
Board.start()
```

In the future, if/when integrating into GUI this can be modified/integrated in the GUI loop

```
while running:
    Board.calculate_nim()
    running = Board.proceed()
```

**Whole code:**

```
import random

class Nim:

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player
        self.num_piles = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.init_piles()

    def init_piles(self):
        self.stones_list = []
        for _ in range(0, self.num_piles):
            self.stones_list.append(random.randint(1, 8))

    def print(self):
        print("Current Board:")
        for i in range(0, self.num_piles):
            print("Pile {}:---{} Stones on this pile-----{}".format(
                i + 1, self.stones_list[i], "O" * self.stones_list[i]))
        print("** 'O' represent stone **")

    def start(self):
        print("Hello {}! Welcome to the Game of Nim".format(self.player))
        while self.proceed():
            self.calculate_nim()

    def calculate_nim(self):
        nim = 0
        for i in self.stones_list:
            nim = nim ^ i
        if nim == 0:
            #If Nim-Sum=0, Player start first
            self.get_input()
        else:
            #If Nim-Sum is not equal to 0, Bot start first
            self.bot_turn()

    def get_number_input(self, prompt, max, allowed=[]):
        num = ''
        while True:
            num = input(prompt)
            if not num.isdigit():
                print("Not a Number, please try again")
            elif int(num) <= 0 or int(num) > max:
                print("Out of Range, please try again")
            elif len(allowed) > 0 and int(num) not in allowed:
                print("No stones in pile, please try again")
            else:
                break
        return int(num)

    def get_input(self):
        pile_pick = self.get_number_input(
            "Which pile you want to remove from? ", len(self.stones_list),
            [i + 1 for i, s in enumerate(self.stones_list) if s > 0])
        num_stones = self.get_number_input(
            "{}, How many stones you want to remove from pile {}? ".format(
            self.player, pile_pick), self.stones_list[pile_pick - 1])

        self.stones_list[pile_pick - 1] -= num_stones

    def bot_turn(self):
        print("BOT's TURN")
        nim = 0
        for i in self.stones_list:
            nim = nim ^ i
    
        counter = 0
        for i in self.stones_list:
            if ((nim ^ i) < i):
                print("Bot take {} stone(s) from Pile {}".format(
                  self.stones_list[counter] - (nim ^ i), counter + 1))
                self.stones_list[counter] = (nim ^ i)
    
                break
            counter = counter + 1
      
    def proceed(self):
        self.print()
        if (self.stones_list == [0] * len(self.stones_list)):
            print("Game Over, Bot Won. Thanks for playing!")
            return False
        return True

Board = Nim(input("Enter Your name: "))
Board.start()
```

Comment: [PEP-8 suggests 4 space indentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation). It's hard to tell what code belongs in which block with 2 spaces. You can use [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to autoformat.

Comment: I would actually recommend having 2 classes -- one for the game logic, and one for the UI logic (CLI, here) -- and put the validation that inputs are correct in the game logic. This allows having unit-tests, as well as reusing the logic through another UI layer.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm aware of spacing, transferring from my ide to here was not as smooth as I'd have liked.

Comment: No problem, but you can still [edit] the post.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is the standard style recommendation for Python. I will try to avoid repeating what they've said.

I would recommend that you look into getting a linter such as [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [Pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) which check your code against PEP-8 and issue useful warnings.

### Unused import

You have the line:

```
from tokenize import Name
```

And never use it, was this debugging? From somewhere else? It can go, especially as you immediately shadow it (make it inaccessible by overwriting its name) within `main`

```
Name=input("Enter Your name:")
```

If I subsequently tried to run (if `tokenize.Name` was callable as a function/constructor)

```
bob = Name("Hello")
```

It would fail because `Name` is now the string I entered.

Avoid shadowing things as it very easily leads to difficult to debug problems.

### Consistency

Again as mentioned by others, consistency of naming, casing and others is useful and a linter will highlight these, but you should also be consistent with other parts of your style. You have both:

```
    print("Hello ",Name,"! Welcome to the Game of Nim")
```

and

```
        print("Pile {}:---{} Stones on this pile-----{}".format(i+1,StoneQuantity,'O'*StoneQuantity))
```

and

```
stones = input(player+", How many stones you want to remove? ")
```

Be consistent within your code and it becomes easier to follow, debug and update.

The more modern, pythonic way to do these would be f-strings:

```
print(f"Pile {i+1}:---{StoneQuantity} Stones on this pile-----{'O'*StoneQuantity}")
```

### DRY (Don't repeat yourself)

You have parts of your code which do (moreorless) the same thing:

```
def Board(StoneList,StonePile,StoneQuantity,player):
    #Print out the board
    for i in range(0,StonePile):
        StoneQuantity=random.randint(1,8)  # N.B. the StoneQuantity passed in 
                                           # Is completely useless and overwritten
        print("Pile {}:---{} Stones on this pile-----{}".format(i+1,StoneQuantity,'O'*StoneQuantity))
        StoneList.append(StoneQuantity)
    print("** 'O' represent stone **")

...

def proceed(StoneList,StonePile,player):
    print("Current Board:")
    for i in range(0,StonePile):
        print("Pile {}:---{} Stones on this pile-----{}".format(i+1,StoneList[i],"O"*StoneList[i]))
    print("** 'O' represent stone **")
    ...
```

Turn this into a function and use it everywhere:

```
def print_board(stone_list: List[int]):
    print("Current Board:")
    for ind, cnt in enumerate(stone_list, 1):  # Python can iterate directly over the list
        print(f"Pile {ind}:---{cnt} Stones on this pile-----{'O'*cnt}")
    print("** 'O' represent stone **")
```

which looks much nicer, and if we want to reformat how we print things, we only have to change it once.

### Returns

Use returns and in your functions to handle passing things around, rather than diving deeper and deeper into functions. This means your main would look something more like:

```
def main():
    n_stone_piles = random.randint(2, 5)
    player = input("Enter Your name:")
    print(f"Hello {player}! Welcome to the Game of Nim")

    stone_list = build_board(n_stone_piles)

    while sum(stone_list) > 0: # While stones exist
        print_board(stone_list)
        stone_list = get_input(stone_list, n_stone_piles, player)
        print_board(stone_list)
        stone_list = calculate_nim(stone_list, n_stone_piles)

    print("Game Over, Bot Won. Thanks for playing!")
```

And, for example, your `build_board` might be:

```
def build_board(n_piles: int, max_stones: int = 8) -> List[int]:
    return [random.randint(1, max_stones) for _ in range(n_piles)]
```

Much simpler, no infinite recursion, much easier to debug.